Including teachings or details that do not improve the odds
There are certain background details or teachings regarding the invention that might be helpful knowledge for someone trying to implement the invention. But this is generally background knowledge, or knowledge around the best context to apply this invention, etc.
These knowledge should have no impact on whether the patent examiner allows it or not.
Should these extra content be removed, especially if the patent application is already lengthy?

If it doesn't hurt and might help, I generally lean towards leaving it in. In the US, there is no fee for up to 100 pages in an application. So, for US filings, if the details do not harm your position, and are accurate, it usually costs you more in Atty time to remove the details than to leave them in.

@Andrew l highly encourage you to post comments like this as formal answers.

If they are worded to not hurt, they may help. On the other hand every word has the possibility to be used again you. Google patent profanity.
